# laravel query, syntax error, unexpected '$out' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I think this is more likely an PHP error, and I found a few posts with the same error, however I can't solve the problem from the answers to those.

My code

```
class consultController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){


        return view('pages.consult');
    }

    public function find(){
        $input=Request::all();
        $location=$input['location'];
        $spec=$input['specialization']

        $out = DB::table('doctors')->where('location','=', $location)
                                       ->where('specialization_group','=', $specialization)
                                       ->get(); //line 23, error here
        return $out;
    }
}
```

The error:

```
FatalErrorException in consultController.php line 23:
syntax error, unexpected '$out' (T_VARIABLE)
```

After resolving the error with semicolon, I'm now getting this error,

```
ErrorException in Factory.php line 153:
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

While trying to pass the $out to a view,

```
class consultController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){


        return view('pages.consult');
    }

    public function find(){
        $input=Request::all();
        $location=$input['location'];
        $spec=$input['specialization'];

        $out = DB::table('doctors')->where('location','=', $location)
                                       ->where('specialization_group','=', $spec)
                                       ->get();
        return view('pages.doclist')->with('out',$out);
        //return count($out);
    }
}
```

Comment: missing semicolon here `$spec=$input['specialization']`

Comment: also use better code editor which shows these kind of errors on the fly

Comment: I don't know why this question has got +1 for just missing semi-colon. -1 from me.

Comment: I'm using sublime text.

Comment: I'm having this error now "ErrorException in Factory.php line 153:
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array " Can anyone help me with that? The code is updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semicolon is missing at the `$spec=$input['specialization']` line.

It should look like this:

`$spec=$input['specialization'];`

Comment: Damn, I feel like pulling my hair. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$out = \DB::table('doctors')->whereLocation(request('location'))
            ->whereSspecializatioGroup(request('specialization'))
            ->get();
```

for laravel 5.1